# Android helloWorld with button

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I've download some code to run but there are problems:

```
package t.t.t4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test4Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    OnClickListener listener1 = null;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listener1 = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                CharSequence text_view_old = text_view.getText();
                text_view.setText("Before: "+ text_view_old +"\nAdded information: Hello World again !");
            }
        };

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
    }
}
```

`R.id.TextView01` is the line that had an error. What is the meaning of R and R.id?

Comment: can you please the error here?

Comment: Have you read [XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) guide?

Comment: Does "TextView01" id exist in your main.xml ?

Comment: If you are using eclipse then you might need to clean you project after deleting the gen folder. It seems you are having compile time errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `setContentView(R.layout.main);` after the `super.onCreate();` because all the widgets are declared in the layout file so first it needs to be loaded. Here `textview` is declared in the `main.xml` file.

That is why it is giving the error, becuase you use that textview before it sets the view.

you have to declare `texview with id TextView01` in your `main.xml` file.

Comment: OP isn't using the textview before it is set. The reference is in an OnClickListener and isn't executed until there is a click.